# How to connect to the database based on the domain?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io, feathersjs

I have an working application in based on feathersjs using mongoose. My application works on 3030 port on public domain address. I want setup the same app on another public domain but in this case I want that a second app connect to another database. I would like the applications works on the same port because in a future I'll have more the same apps on different domain and it will be tire when I have to change something. How can I use one app on one port with different mongo database. I use authenticate JWT in my project.